# DNS Manager (Win 2012) only displays a partial list of records

Tags: domain-name-system

I have not been able to locate anything on the web to address this issue I am having with DNS Manager on a 2012 box.

Basically, I am running DNS Manager on box-A and I am looking at DNS Servers on both box-A and box-B. Box-B is running core 2012 if that sheds any light on anything.

In a nutshell, I can only see a small portion of our DNS records. I have Domain Admin rights. My associates with the same permissions groups are able to view all the records in the domain.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DNS management is granted thought membership in the "DNS Admins" group, not domain admins. Do you have a filter in place?

Comment: I will double check, but my permissions were supposed to mirror the other admins. I will put "eyes on" and make sure though.

Comment: As I thought, my permissions appear to be good. Domain Admins should have the dns perms built in.